# Designing sidebarPanel with navbarPage

Tags: r, shiny

I got this UI 
[image: myUI]

(reproductible code):

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("tab1", checkboxInput("opt1", "opt1 for 1 tab")),
      tabPanel("tab2", checkboxInput("opt2", "opt2 for 2 tab"))
    )
  ),
  mainPanel(
    navbarPage("choose page",
      navbarMenu("page1", 
                 tabPanel("panel1", 
                          mainPanel(plotOutput("plot1"))
                          ), 
                 tabPanel("panel2", plotOutput("plot2"))
                 ),


      navbarMenu("page2", tabPanel("panel3", plotOutput("plot3")), tabPanel("panel4", plotOutput("plot4")))
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output){

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I want to add in sidebarPanel:

1. checkboxInput ONLY for `page1` and `panel1`
2. checkboxInput ONLY for `page1` (common for `panel1` and `panel2`)

is it possible with shiny?

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, put an `id` to the `navbarPage` and use `conditionalPanel`:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    conditionalPanel(
      'input.navbar == "panel1"',
      checkboxInput("checkbox1", "Hello")
    ),
    conditionalPanel(
      'input.navbar == "panel1" || input.navbar == "panel2"',
      checkboxInput("checkbox1", "Goodbye")
    )
  ),
  mainPanel(
    navbarPage("choose page",
               navbarMenu("page1", 
                          tabPanel("panel1", 
                                   mainPanel(plotOutput("plot1"))
                          ), 
                          tabPanel("panel2", plotOutput("plot2"))
               ),
               navbarMenu("page2", tabPanel("panel3", plotOutput("plot3")), tabPanel("panel4", plotOutput("plot4"))),
               id = "navbar"
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Why it doesn't work good?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage("Choose page: " ,
    navbarMenu("Discovering the dataset",
      sidebarPanel(
                  checkboxInput("x", "x")
      ),

                tabPanel("volume", mainPanel(plotOutput("pp"))),
                tabPanel("amount salary"),
                tabPanel("map"),
                tabPanel("data"),
                tabPanel("animation"),
                tabPanel("wordcloud")

    ),
    navbarMenu("Options"),
    navbarMenu("More information")

)
)


server <- function(input, output){
  output$pp <- reactivePlot({plot(1,1)})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

here I want the checkbox for all barpage `Discovering the dataset`